# proof: no infinite bounded discrete set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> A set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is said to be a discrete set if $S'=\emptyset$.
>   A set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is said to be an isolated set if $S\cap S'=\emptyset$.

1. Give an example of an infinite discrete set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.
2. Give an example of a bounded discrete set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$.
3. Can there be an infinite bounded discrete set $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$?

**My attempt**

1. $S=\mathbb{N}$
2. $S=\{1,2,3\}$
3. I am unable to think of an example. If the answer is no, is there a proof for it? Do we use the following result to prove this?
   If $S$ is a non-empty bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $\sup(S),\inf(S)\in\overline{S}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bolzano -Weirstrass Theorem says that any bounded infinite set has a limit point. So the answer to 3) is NO.